# Why netbeans is still in 7.0?

Tags: netbeans

I wonder why NetBeans 7.0 is still in Software Center and is not replaced by 7.4?

Netbeans 7.0.1  Released August 1, 2011

Comment: This was previously closed against [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) but that doesn't go any distance to answer the question. The current version in 13.10 is 7.0.1. There have been [half a dozen releases](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html) before 13.10 was released since 7.0.1. The traditional SRU-et-al answer doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it just takes too long for a software to be updated in the repositories, and unless you can wait or give your contribution to the community by packaging it yourself, you're probably going to need to install it manually... the good thing is that it's normally very easy to do. Specially when talking about such a widely used software.

I remember having the very same problem with the TexLive distribution packaged in ubuntu. It was years outdated.

I believe the problem is really the lack of volunteers for the upgrading process.

Comment: Debian also have 7.0.1(wheezzy,jessie,sid), i guess ubuntu just drag and drop the package. I wonder if there is some bug in debian or something.

Comment: It is not Canonical that takes too long.

Comment: Sorry for this... I'm not very acquainted with the whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

Because the package has not been updated in Debian and Ubuntu uses the debian packages. Even Trusty is going to be 7.0.1+dfsg1-5ubuntu2. Looking at [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673606) Debian seems to have problems with maintainership:

> **Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2013 13:47:49 +0100** Since I switched to phpStorm, I no longer use netbeans. So I have no plans to package netbeans, sorry!

and

> **Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 09:05:42 +0100** Netbeans 7.4 should hopefully be released in a week or so (based on previous release cycles) and I've managed to get rc1 building OK.
>   There's a few other updates still required (for which I've got very
>   rough packaging in place locally) - I've been tracking these on
>   https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Netbeans.
>
> If you'd like to help with any of this then you're more then welcome,
>   under the Java Maintainers team. Pick a dependency update you'd like to
>   work on and let me know so I can share what I've got so far. Equally, if
>   you've got upload rights and are willing to sponsor uploads then that
>   would be useful - jchardet for example is awaiting sponsorship, and once
>   eclipselink-jpa-2.1-spec gets through the new queue then I've got an
>   eclipselink update which will need looking at.

Almost the whole year 2013 it had no maintainer (or one that did not a lot) and looking at the [project](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Netbeans) it seems 1 person is doing all the work since 2013.10.